# mule file catch lock exception

Tags: file, exception, mule

I'm using the file connector below in a cluster environment

```
<file:connector
    name="inputZip"
    pollingFrequency="1000"
    streaming="false"
    autoDelete="true"
    workDirectory="/home/sergio/compartilhado/temp">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.file.FileMuleMessageFactory"/>
</file:connector>`
```

sometimes when one node of the cluster lock a file the other node try to read the same file and throws the exception

```
15:37:37,826 ERROR [org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy] ([sample].inputZip.receiver.01) 
********************************************************************************
Message               : File "teste.zip" does not exist or cannot be read
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-11007
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. File "teste.zip" does not exist or cannot be read (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
  org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver:608 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: File "teste.zip" does not exist or cannot be read
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.attemptFileLock(FileMessageReceiver.java:608)
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.processFile(FileMessageReceiver.java:290)
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.poll(FileMessageReceiver.java:238)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I want to log another message or treat this error before it's thrown. Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance

Comment: HA is an EE feature, have you tried contacting MuleSoft Support?

Comment: Yes, I post a question in Mule forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem extending the class FileMessageReceiver and overriding the method below

```
public void processFile(File file) throws MuleException {
    try {
        super.processFile(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Fail to read file " + e);
    }
}
```

In my connector I've added in the tag service-overrides the attribute messageReceiver="br.com.unimed.wsd.tiss.mule.batch.FileSampleMessageFactory"

Comment: Above work , however  code will never reach  'logger.info' statement as exception is handled in parent class "FileMessageReceiver.java" invoking default exception strategy . Tested in mule 3.6.4